# How to write arduino code in a c/c++ script

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, c, core-libraries

I'm pretty new to arduino. But I have some knowledge about programming in c/c++. I know that arduino is written in c. But it can't be used as normal c/c++ code.
for example ,
instead of including some libraries and write the code like this..

```
#include "arduino.h"


int main(){

    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

    while(1){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    .....
    }
}
```

We have to write it using functions defined in arduino.

```
void setup(){
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    .....
}
```

But I have some other libraries and programmes and stuff written in c and c++ and I need to use some arduino code in it and compile. So my question is, is there a way to write arduino in pure c/c++ as in first code snippet.

*I may not need arduino for this. My main target is to use servos, sensors in programms written in c/c++. But I would like to know what is the best way.

Comment: It is unclear to me, what exactly your problem is. Arduino code is C++ code. The only difference is what the IDE does before compiling (automatically including arduino.h and writing function prototypes for your defined functions, so that they can be placed whereever you want). The "Arduino functions" are defined in the header files, which are included via arduino.h. Are you trying to program an Arduino without the Arduino framework? Or do you just want to know how to avoid `pinMode()` and `digitalWrite()`?

Comment: Note: Your first code is just invalid C/C++, because you execute code outside of any function (the `pinMode()` function in this case)

Comment: Thanks I didn't noticed it. What I need to do is combine arduino code to my other c++ programs which uses servos and some sensors in some instances. When I use the ide I have to use setup() and loop() functions. What I need to know is can I write the code as in the first snippet and upload it into the board. If possible, how? Because arduino ide only support .ino files. not .cpp . What I meant by "best way" is that, should I use arduino for controlling servos and sensors or find some other way to connect them to my programmes.

Comment: So your question is more about the general project layout? What other C++ programs do you have, that need to be integrated with Arduino? When having programs on a PC and needing to interface peripherals like sensors and servos it is common to use an Arduino (or any other microcontroller), write a program for it to use the sensors  and servos and communicate with the PC over Serial/USB. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. Should I need to upload the code to the board in order to use the sensors. It's certainly not possible. I'm building a device for reading and copying books. I have few c++ libraries written with opencv for image proccessing part and calculations. I planned to use arduino for the book handling device. I'm not sure is that possible as described in the question.

Comment: You won't run OpenCV code on the Arduino: it's not powerful enough for that. You will most likely have to write multiple programs that communicate and work together: one running on the Arduino for handling the books, an another one running on your computer for doing the image processing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino IDE uses C++ not C.

You don't **have** to use `setup` and `loop`. This is a valid Arduino sketch:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int main ()
  {
  init ();  // initialize timers
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Hello, world");
  Serial.flush (); // let serial printing finish
  }  // end of main
```

> But I would like to know what is the best way.

The way that works best for you. The IDE gives you some convenience functions. You don't have to use them. You can look at the datasheet and directly address the hardware registers.

See [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/bbshowpost.php?id=12625) for a few more details.

Comment: But how do I upload this to the board. If not possible how to connect the board to my c++ programs. ide is only compettible with .ino files.

Comment: @Alien5516788: you can easily convert a C++ program into a .ino program: just change the file extension to `.ino`.

Comment: You use the IDE to upload what I posted to the board. That was an Arduino "sketch". Plus, you can put C++ files into the same folder as the .INO files.

Comment: Did you read the link I mentioned in my answer? That shows using C++ files.

Comment: @Alien5516788, To be clear, *only* .ino/.pde files are subject to the kind of preprocessing that makes the Arduino "language" different from ordinary C++. The core, core libraries, and system libraries are all written in a mixture of .c/.cpp/.h files (broadly non-INO files) as is the majority (if not entirety) of most non-core libraries. The bulk code going into any typical Arduino project is in fact written in ordinary C++ (or C) code, whether the end user understands this or not. You are likewise not required to write much of any of your own code within .ino files.

Comment: Thanks, I read your article. I was trying to upload .cpp files to arduino board. Now it's all clear. Also I need to know how .ino files work. As described in the article, Arduino.h is included in .cpp file and .ino file is empty. How is that gonna work.

Comment: The IDE compiles **all** the .cpp files and links them together. So an empty .ino file isn't a big deal. The #include directives in the .ino file tell the IDE which libraries to include (link).

Comment: @Nick Gammon: The solution you gave here http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/bbshowpost.php?id=12625 is good but the justification less so since all 3 of your examples of bad prototype generation have, at least with IDE 1.8.19 and probably earlier, been fixed. If you still need to illustrate this with an example which currently fails, here is one: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder/issues/362

Comment: @6v6gt Ah, that was written 8 years ago. Like many things in the computer industry, old code does not necessarily travel well.

Comment: Indeed. The one positive thing about the Arduino automatic prototype generation feature is that there are simple work-arounds to avoid unwittingly using it. I'm sure that if we could go back in time, with our present knowledge, that feature would not have emerged in its current form.